# How to Avoid calling setState Function Again and Again?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and I need to update the State of a variable only when the value is different from the  previous state.
Suppose I have a state with initial value `false`

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
```

I need to update the state of the variable on Horizontal Scroll, I have attached a listener on Scroll that will call a function handleClickAway everytime, I scroll

```
useEffect(() => {
   const scroll = document.querySelector('.myclass');
   scroll.addEventListener("scroll", () => handleClickAway());
   return () => {
       scroll.removeEventListener("scroll", () => handleClickAway());
   };
}, []);

const handleClickAway = () => {
    setOpen(false);
}
```

Now, here it will update the state everytime by calling `setOpen(false)` on Scroll, I am not sure how to handle this

I don't want to call the `setOpen(false)` again if it has already been called and set the value to `false` on Scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the if statement and call `setOpen` only if `open` is `true`.

```
const handleClickAway = () => {
    if (open) {
      setOpen(false);
    }
}
```

Or a bit shorter way:

```
const handleClickAway = () => {
  open && setOpen(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
const handleClickAway = () => open && setOpen(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleClickAway = () => {
 if(open) {
   setOpen(false);
 }
}
```